# Getting stuck while trying to upload images to a specific user account in Imgur

Tags: angular, image-uploading, imgur

I've created an **Angular** application which uploads images to Imgur. I've found ways to **anonymously** upload images to Imgur. I'm getting stuck when I'm trying to upload images to a specific user account.

Looking at the Imgur API and following the steps, I'm able to get the access token inside **POSTMAN**
and then use the access token inside the header and send requests. I want to get the access token inside my application itself rather than posting requests inside POSTMAN. From what I've understood, for using it inside my application I need to make a call to:

https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=REQUESTED_RESPONSE_TYPE&state=APPLICATION_STATE

How do I make the call to the above URL, get the response and then store the access_token from the response URL inside an Angular application. Because I've already tried sending **GET** request to the above URL inside Angular application and the above URL returns a HTML document and I didn't understand where to display this returned HTML document so I tried rendering it inside a **DIV** element which I think is a wrong choice. Now the HTML document is properly rendered inside the div element but the problem occurs when I'm trying to enter username and password inside the rendered HTML document, I get an error saying you cannot **POST** from 'https://localhost:4200/'.

I'm clearly doing something wrong and I don't understand how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should display/appeend returned html by following url in Modal dialog box instead of `<div>` tag.  On Modal dialog box should **POST** to server.

\https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&response_type=REQUESTED_RESPONSE_TYPE&state=APPLICATION_STATE

Comment: So when I try to send a GET request to the link, I receive the HTML page which I try to render inside a Modal dialog box. How should I send a POST request to the same link inside the Modal dialog box?

Comment: There are two options (1) From Modal.component.ts by adding a button that POST directly to the URL. (2) in Modal.component.ts write EventEmitter as @Output property that contains payload and emits to parent page. From parent page POST to above Url. Parent.component.html 
<parent-modal-comp (submit)=responseFromModal($event)> </parent-modal-comp>

Modal.component.ts
export calss ModalComponent {
@Output() submitted = new EventEmitter<any>
private submit(){ }
}